# Azure multi-tenant app read/write to storage account using RBAC

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

Can two Azure Tenants (with RBAC) use a storage account for data exchange? We tried and getting 401 error. Any help to resolve this is much appreciated.

Below is our scenario...

Tenant 1: tenantA

Multi Tenant App: appA (daemon app type)

Tenant 2: tenantB

Storage Account: storageB

Tenant Admin consent "appA" and grant 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' application permission on storageB. Below is how we set permissions (We choose Microsoft Graph User.Read.All for lack knowledge what else to choose)
[image]

Now, Can tenantA write to storageB using Azure Storage SDK?

Well, we are getting below exception when we tried!

```
Azure.RequestFailedException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.
RequestId:ab6e2992-001e-0089-16dd-d52538000000
Time:2020-12-19T08:07:07.8901668Z
Status: 401 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.)
Error Code: InvalidAuthenticationInfo

Headers:
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id:
```

Comment: Are you able to just use the storage account keys?

Comment: This is now resolved, issue was...
We switched using app host tenant ID (tenantA) to consented tenant ID (tenantB).

Comment: If your issue was solved, you can post it as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @user3023949 Hey, thanks for your contribution. I post an answer for others to refer. Of course I would delete it if you post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **yes** that two Azure Tenants (with RBAC) can use a storage account for data exchange.

Thanks for user3023949's contribution, I post the answer here for others to refer:

What you need is make tenantB consent the application client id rather than tenantA. And you can do it through the URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id}
```

> where:
>
> {client-id} is the application's client ID (also known as app ID).
>
> {tenant-id} is your organization's tenant ID or any verified domain
> name.

Follow [Construct the URL for granting tenant-wide admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#construct-the-url-for-granting-tenant-wide-admin-consent).